# Lookup LDAP entries from inside LdapAuthoritiesPopulator

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm using Spring Security and `spring-security-ldap` for authentication in a Spring Boot application.

I want to implement an `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` that looks up some entries from the LDAP server to decide the roles of the user. These entries are not under the user, so the `userData` object provided to `getGrantedAuthorities` method is not enough. (I have no control over the LDAP server so I cannot add the roles to user entries).

I thought about injecting the `ContextSource` that Spring Security creates when calling `auth.ldapAuthentication().contextSource()` (see (1) in the code below) into the `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`. But that doesn't work because the `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator` is created before the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, and so the `ContextSource` does not exist yet.

My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` contains the following method:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource() // (1)
                .url("ldap://example.org/o=organization")
                .and()
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator)
            .userSearchFilter("uid={0}");
}
```

`ldapAuthoritiesPopulator` is autowired, the class is currently a dummy implementation that simply adds `ROLE_USER`:

```
@Component
public class CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(
        DirContextOperations userData, String username) {

        // I want to look up some entries in LDAP here, so I need a ContextSource
        // but I can't inject it because it does not exist when this bean is created

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the roles populated till after the application is running (I suppose). So one thing that would work would be to inject the `ApplicationContext` instead of the `ContextSource` and look up the latter lazily. If that works  there might be a truck with `@Lazy`.